# Cartesian envelope of a symmetric monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there a left adjoint to the forgetful functor from cartesian monoidal categories to symmetric monoidal categories? And if so: how can it be described explicitely.

In more detail: Given a symmetric monoidal category $\mathbb V$ i am looking for a monoidal functor

$$\chi:\mathbb V \to \mathcal C(\mathbb V)$$

into a cartesian monoidal category $\mathcal C(\mathbb V)$ such that every other monoidal functor

$$\varphi:\mathbb V \to \mathbb C $$

into a cartesian monoidal category $\mathbb C$ factors 'uniquely' over $\chi$.

Comment: what is a cartesian monoidal category? Do you mean a (symmetrical) monoidal closed one?


Comment: "A cartesian monoidal category (usually just called a cartesian category), is a monoidal category whose monoidal structure is given by the category-theoretic product (and so whose unit is a terminal object)."

-- http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category

Comment: You look for a $2$-adjoint, right? See also the comments in Chris' answer. You don't want that $\hom(V,U(C))$ and $\hom(C(V),C)$ are isomorphic, but rather that they are equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a left adjoint. Both the category $\textbf{Mon}$ of (symmetric) monoidal categories, and the category $\textbf{Cart}$ of Cartesian categories, are algebraic over the category $\textbf{Cat}$ of categories. That is, there are monads on $\textbf{Cat}$ whose categories of algebras are $\textbf{Mon}$ and $\textbf{Cart}$, respectively.

More interestingly, there is also a *right* adjoint, that sends a monoidal category $\textbf{C}$ to the category of comonoids in $\textbf{C}$. This is a [classic result by Thomas Fox](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927877608822127).

Comment: It seems that the link doesn't work. I'm willing to take a look at Fox's paper. The results looks like very interesting.

Comment: Fernando, you need to remove "classic result" from the link. Don't know how it got there. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927877608822127

Comment: Shouldn't Mon and Cart be treated as 2-categories as opposed to 1-categories?  Or is there some magic working behind the scenes that ensures that issues with higher coherences do not arise?

Comment: Dmitri, definitely they are 2-cateogries. I'm pretty sure that 1-categorically those algebraicity statements are false. E.g. associators correspond to associativity conditions in algebraic 2-theory, cartesian structure is encoded in adjunction between diagonal and multiplication, etc. But formally this doesn't seem to change anything, classical adjunction proofs can be repeated 2-categorically.

Comment: I should have specified that Fox uses strict monoidal functors as the morphisms. As Dmitri points out and Anton mentions, lax (or even strong) monoidal functors require 2-categories.

Comment: Thanks for the link; how can said monads - and the left adjoint - be described explicitly? Any reference?

Comment: As usual with these abstract proofs you can trace them back and find explicit constructions - which are not really useful. Here, when your monoidal category is given by generators and relations, you just replace $\otimes$ by $\times$ in each relation. A basic example is the ($2$-)free symmetric monoidal category on one object, which is the permutation groupoid. Then the left adjoint maps it to the free cartesian category on one object, which should be $\mathsf{FinSet}^{\mathsf{op}}$. Such things get interesting when you really work out *specific* examples where no presentation is given.

Comment: The argument need a DUbuc theorem (see "TOposes Triple and theories" BArr-Wells  Th.2(b) p.137 ; or H. Shubert "CAtegories" 21.5.3 p. 342)

Comment: I see a problem: monoidal morphism aren't algebraic morphisms inj the algebraic presentation (strict monoidal  functors are).